# Load Runner:Why the transactions go to stop?

Tags: transactions, loadrunner

I had run my scenario some times and got the similar result —— There are tens of "stop" in the "Transaction Summary" table of the "Summary Report". but our "performance standard" not allow contain any "stop".

I tried to remove the rendezvous from the script and run the scenario. As a result, the "stop" count reduce to 1 even 0. but removing the rendezvous is go against to the test plan. It is not allowed.

I have searched out that "stop" represents "This is the count of iterations which were halted".

http://www.wilsonmar.com/lr_rpts.htm

But I still don't know how to destroy the "stop".

Thank you for any helps in in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What does your trainer/mentor suggest is the issue?

See concept of six sigma manufacturing quality control and understand why 100% success may be a goal but a very pricey one indeed